# SQL rolling sum giving an unexpected error

Tags: sql, sum, window-functions

I am trying to find the cumulative sum of a column partitioned by month and ordered by Id.
I am getting this error.

```
 column "amount_paid" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

The code

```
select 
    month,
    Id,
    SUM(amount_paid) OVER(PARTITION BY month ORDER BY Id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Col2
from table
where month >= '2022-01-01' 
and Id between 0 and 12
group by month,Id
order by month,Id

Data
month       |  Id  | amount paid
2022-01-01  |  1   |  5866
2022-01-01  |  2   |  8466
2022-01-01  |  3   |  6816
2022-02-01  |  1   |  855
2022-02-01  |  2   |  9821
2022-02-01  |  3   |  3755
```

Comment: I don't think this is the SQL that gave that error.  please show the sql and error you have.  Also what is the definition of the table -- is the column amount_paid or [amount paid]?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only **one** tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

I *suspect* that you  want a cumulative *sum of the monthly sums* for each `id`. If so, then you need to use an aggregate function within the window function:

```
select month, id,
    SUM(amount_paid) AS amount_paid_this_month_for_this_id,
    SUM(SUM(amount_paid)) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY month) AS amount_paid_so_far_for_this_id
from table
where month >= '2022-01-01' 
and Id between 0 and 12
group by month, id
order by month, id
```